# What is the well-known result used to prove primality of $n=2pq+1$ under certain conditions?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, primality-test

On [Henri Lifchitz's website](http://www.primenumbers.net/Henri/us/Testapp1us.htm), we find:

> If $n=2pq+1$, $p$ and $q$ primes and $q>2p$, if there is an integer $a$ such $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ and $\gcd(a^{2p}-1,n)=1$ then $n$ is prime.

It is described as a special case of a "well known" result involving $n=hq^k+1$ with $h=2p$, $p$ and $q$ are prime and $k=1$.

*Question*: What is the well-known result?  Where can we find a proof of it?

Aside from its intrinsic interest, analysis of the proof of this result might be helpful for answering this question [Primality Test with some condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/494251/91818), which includes the case $10p+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have $a^{n-1} = a^{2pq} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$, but $\gcd(a^{2p}-1,n) = 1$, then for any prime $r$ dividing $n$, we have $a^{2p} \not\equiv 1 \pmod{r}$, but $a^{2pq} \equiv 1 \pmod{r}$, thus the order of $a$ modulo $r$ is a multiple of $q$, hence $r \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$, in particular $r \geqslant q+1$. But $(q+1)^2 > n$, so $n$ can have only one prime factor.

Comment: Thanks for that!  (Note: I fixed the transcription error.)